# Get the 4th column base on the columns from other sheet

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I need a Google Sheet formula for a very complex situation...

I have optins sheet contains a table of values

```
A = step
B = min
C = max
D = rate
```

then on data sheet contains

```
A = step
B = number
C = result
```

What I need to find is the result column

I have to match the number (B) of data sheet to which row of optins sheet should it match.

So in this file, will need to lookup 89 from numbers (b) column and cart from step (A) column.

In optins sheet, cart is row 2-7 then 89 is between 50 (B min) and 150 (C max) that's why it will pull up 9%.

what would be the google sheet formula for this complex situation?

File:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Ig8dlYnKRSoCIiw4rTSG3NKyrnVY-uOPocYi6ytSrX8/edit?usp=sharing

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is longer, but more dynamic and you only need a single formula. Also, you can jumble the row order of min and max values and will still work.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(B2:B4,SORT(FILTER(optins!B2:D,optins!A2:A=A2),1,TRUE),3,TRUE))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In C2 of 'Data' try

```
=iferror(vlookup($B2, filter(optins!$B$2:$D, optins!$A$2:$A=$A2), 3, 1))
```

or

```
=iferror(filter(optins!$D$2:$D, optins!$A$2:$A=$A2, B2>=optins!$B$2:$B,$B2<optins!$C$2:$C))
```

and fill down as far as needed.

See if that works?

Comment: hi, thank you this also works.. thank you.. for other's reference, this works per line and need to copy it all the way down